# Ubuntu 4K TV sync issues

Tags: xorg, lenovo, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I have an issue with what I think is a sync problem when I connect my Sony X830C 4K tv to my laptop which is a Lenovo T470s with Intel HD 520 graphics.

The TV is connected via displayport to an active HDMI adapter to allow 60hz which is working flawlessly on Windows 7. I've used this setup for a bit over a year now on Windows but just changed over to Ubuntu.

The sync problem only happens in the lower part of the screen. Like a band from across the whole width of the screen.

I recorded a video of the issue as it's quite hard to explain: https://youtu.be/Y6b70Kp2shQ

This is what I've tried so far to resolve this problem.

- Updating laptop bios
- Updating to 19.04
- Oibaf open graphics drivers
- Creating an X11 configuration file with the following content, tried multiple versions of these options

  Section "Device"
      Identifier      "Intel Graphics"
      Driver          "intel"
      Option          "TripleBuffer"  "true"
      Option          "TearFree"      "true"
      Option          "DRI"           "2"
      Option          "AccelMethod"   "SNA"
  EndSection
- Wayland
- Different refresh rates

Sometimes it disappears for example when you log out and in again only to come back again if for example the screen goes to sleep. It also never happens on the login screen or at 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this would be appreciated!

Comment: @tatsu `nouveau` is only for Nvidia cards. The options here are 1. the default Intel open-source driver of the specific release or 2. some other non-official version provided by a PPA that may or may not be more up-to-date than the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia TIL, I though nouveau was multi-architecture. he should probably try obilaf's ppa.